# Copy component features to Instantiate object?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to add component to Instantiate object. This new component is audioSource. Now I added the audio to the Instantiate but I want to copy all features from "_sound" to the new component.

```
 public AudioSource _sound;
 public float targetCompass;
 public GameObject ebullet;

  Void Start() {
      _sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

   }

 Void Update() {
 if (targetCompass <= 5 )
     {
      GameObject bullets = Instantiate(ebullet) as GameObject;
      bullets.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
      bullets.GetComponent<AudioSource>() = _sound;
     }
```

}

Comment: Why not pre-configure your `ebullet` prefab with the audio source and all the settings you want in the inspector (using copy component/paste component for convenience), so you don't have to do it in script at runtime?

Comment: you right. the problem is I made a big mistake and now to do what you said it will be really bad. may take days. I'm trying to figure any shorts way to solve this problem. To copy audio component features will be easy. Is there a way to do that.

Comment: Want to edit your question to describe the mistake you made and why you think it will take days to solve? Folks might be able to suggest more efficient solutions to that root problem than the one you've thought of so far.

Comment: [Script](https://hastebin.com/upotohekov.cs). when my MachineGun fire, the sound looks annoying or not clear because the speed of rate-fire. If there a way to copy all features of audio component to another one by script will be great.

Comment: Would you like to **edit your question** to include this code, explain how its behaviour differs from what you want, and explain why you think copying the AudioSource to the bullet after instantiation would be the right solution?

Comment: No, just answer my question please. My TD game have over 40 guns with different pitches and I'm already had several scenes/levels made. Just tell me how to copy component features.

Comment: @user43474 This is not how stack exchange works. Comments are temporary. Their purpose is to find out how the question could be improved. Any relevant information found out through comments should be edited into the question.

Comment: Simply: No. If you want free help from strangers, you have to be willing to work together with us. Copying components at runtime is a poor solution to your problem. I'm confident we can find a better solution to your problem that won't take days to implement if you're willing to collaborate together. The longer you fight the folks trying to help you, the longer it will take to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Run this from an Editor script to copy your AudioSource to the prefab:

```
 UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.CopyComponent(source.GetComponent<AudioSource>());
 UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.PasteComponentAsNew(source.ebullet);
```

This does not work at runtime, but you can update your prefabs in the Editor and then they'll be good to go at runtime. If you need to do this for many objects, use a loop.